# Check if subarray with sum 0 exists or not

Tags: c, arrays

Please find the loopholes in this piece of code to check if a subarray with sum 0 exists in the given array (I am not getting the required output). I am new to programming, so any tips, suggestions are welcome. I earnestly want to improve. Also, please let me know in the comments if i can use some other logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int compare(const void* a,const void* b);
void FindO(int * A, int n);

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    int A[] = {-7,-4,-3,1,2,3,10};
    n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    qsort(A,n, sizeof(int), compare);
    printf("The sorted array is: ");
    for (i = 0;i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
        }
    FindO(A, n);
    return 0;
    }

int compare(const void* a,const void* b)
{
    int l = *(int *)a;
    int r = *(int *)b;

    return (l-r);
    }

void FindO(int * A, int n)
{
    int mid = n/2;
    int i, j = mid;
    int sum = A[mid];
    printf("\n%d ", sum);
    while(i >= 0 && j <n)
    {
        if(sum ==0)
        {printf("\nFound it!");
            return;}
        else if(sum > 0)
        {
            i--;
            sum = sum + A[i];

            }
        else
        {
            j++;
            sum = sum + A[j];

            }
        }
    if(sum !=0)
    {printf("\nNot found Buddy!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What output do you get? What output did you expect? And perhaps it's time for you to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thankyou for the link. I'll delete this question and try to debug the code on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what is your problem.
But to start with, you don't initialize `i` which will most likely cause a segmentation fault when you use it:

```
 while(i >= 0 && j <n)
```

or in the subsequent references to it.

You can define variables together separated by `,` comma, but the initialization:

```
int i, j = mid;
```

Is only affecting `j` and not `i`.

Comment: The initialization of i was creating problems. Thank you. Any other approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your algorithm gets all subarrays of an array, so I have written my own solutions.
This one sums all the elements of subarrays in an array with recursion and checks if the sum is equal to zero:

```
void FindO_in(const int *A, size_t n, int sum, size_t numslen)
{
    assert(A != NULL);
    assert(n >= 0);
    assert(numslen >= 0);

    if (n == 0) {
        if (numslen == 0) {
            // no numbers summed, ignored
            return;
        }
        if (sum != 0) return;
        if (sum == 0) {
            printf("Zero pal!");
        } else {
            printf("Not zero buddy!");
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    --n;

    // next without incrementing sum
    FindO_in(&A[1], n, sum, numslen);

    // protec against overflow
    assert(!(A[0] > 0 ? (sum > INT_MAX - A[0]) : (sum < INT_MIN - A[0])));
    // next with incremented sum
    sum += A[0];
    ++numslen;
    FindO_in(&A[1], n, sum, numslen);
}

void FindO(const int *A, size_t n)
{
    FindO_in(A, n, 0, 0);
}
```

The below is a more generic solution. First i generate all the subararys of an array using recursion. Then for each of the subarray i call a callback, which checks if the sum of elements of this subarray is equal to zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define try(expr)  ((expr) ? (void)0 : (assert(expr), (void)fprintf(stderr, "Expression `%s` failed\n", #expr), abort()))

static void check0(const int *arr, size_t n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        try(!(arr[0] > 0 ? (sum > INT_MAX - arr[0]) : (sum < INT_MIN - arr[0])));
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    if (sum != 0) return;
    printf("The sum of numbers {");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("} is equal %d. ", sum);
    if (sum == 0) {
        printf("Zero pal!");
    } else {
        printf("Not zero buddy!");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static void gensubarrays_in(const int *arr, size_t n, int *subarr, size_t subarrlen, void (*callback)(const int*, size_t))
{
    assert(arr != NULL);
    assert(n >= 0);
    assert(subarr != NULL);

    if (n == 0) {
        // empty subarray - ignore
        if (subarrlen == 0) return;

        callback(subarr, subarrlen);

        return;
    }
    --n;
    gensubarrays_in(&arr[1], n, subarr, subarrlen, callback);
    subarr[subarrlen++] = arr[0];
    gensubarrays_in(&arr[1], n, subarr, subarrlen, callback);
}

static void gensubarrays(const int *arr, size_t n, void (*callback)(const int*, size_t))
{
    // just a temp variable, to know, which numbers are summed
    int *subarr = calloc(sizeof(int), n);
    try(subarr != NULL);
    gensubarrays_in(arr, n, subarr, 0, callback);
    free(subarr);
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {-7,-4,-3,1,2,3,10};
    const size_t n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);

    printf("The array is: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    gensubarrays(A, n, check0);

    return 0;
}
```

: )

Comment: @Cuk Thankyou. Any tips, suggestions on how I can improve? I want to write codes the way you write. I mean using assertions, function callbacks. I know all of these, but I dont use them, Dont know why.

Comment: Thank you. Just code, the more the better. You just learn via experience. Try to use one [coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html), use assertion to catch bugs (bad function parameters), callbacks are used to write generic functions, just like [qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). [Break complex problems into a set of small problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). You can always practice by answering questions on stackoverflow like me... ; )